# ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1715)) - Failed to start namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to restart one of the namenode (nn2) but i get the following error in the logs:

> 

```
2021-12-17 10:23:53,676 ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1715)) - Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputException: Error replaying edit log at offset 0.  Expected transaction ID was 274488049
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadEditRecords(FSEditLogLoader.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadFSEdits(FSEditLogLoader.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadEdits(FSImage.java:890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:745)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1090)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:632)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:694)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:937)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:910)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1643)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1710)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream$PrematureEOFException: got premature end-of-file at txid 274488048; expected file to go up to 274488109
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream.nextOp(RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.readOp(EditLogInputStream.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.skipUntil(EditLogInputStream.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.RedundantEditLogInputStream.nextOp(RedundantEditLogInputStream.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.readOp(EditLogInputStream.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadEditRecords(FSEditLogLoader.java:213)
        ... 12 more
2021-12-17 10:23:53,678 INFO  util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(210)) - Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputException: Error replaying edit log at offset 0.  Expected transaction ID was 274488049
2021-12-17 10:23:53,681 INFO  namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(51)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at XX-XXX-XX-XXXX.XXXXX.XX/XX.X.XX.XX
************************************************************/
```

i tryied to do the following steps in order to solve the issue:

i copied from nn01 to the NameNode directories of nn02 the following logs
edits_0000000000274487928-0000000000274488048

edits_0000000000274488049-0000000000274488109

So far the nn02 is still not starting and i get the same error.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If that is an HA setup, and your NN1 is working properly. Format your NN2(hdfs namenode -format) and do a bootstrap (hdfs namenode -bootstrapStandby)
Then try restarting the NN2.